# socket.io-client: Get handshake headers

Tags: websocket, socket.io, socket.io-client

In order to preserve session across reconnections (using `express-session`), I'm trying to access the headers of a handshake.

I couldn't find any way to access them (the client API completely ignores the handshake).

My idea is to use the handshake headers to construct future reconnection attempts (so the session will continue on).

How can I access it?